# not able to convert integer data type to bigserial in postgres

Tags: postgresql

For converting integer datatype to bigserial in postgres I have run below command but it didn't change its datatype but it's changing the modifiers

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id;
ALTER TABLE user_event_logs ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE user_event_logs ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('id');
ALTER SEQUENCE id OWNED BY user_event_logs.id;
```

After running this it is showing output like this

```
Column Type  Modifiers  this all my column heading and id  integer  not null
```

i want to change type to bigserial

Answer (score 4):

bigserial is a shortcut for bigint + sequence + default value, so if you want `user_event_logs.id` to be `bigint`, instead of `int`, use:

```
ALTER TABLE user_event_logs ALTER COLUMN id type bigint;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

> The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types,
>   but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier
>   columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some
>   other databases).

also:

> The type names serial and serial4 are equivalent: both create integer
>   columns. The type names bigserial and serial8 work the same way,
>   except that they create a bigint column.

so if you want `bigserial`, just alter volumn type to `bigint`

Comment: I think he don't have sequence at all, so we must create it all from the beginning.

Comment: well, then its just `create table user_event_logs (id bigserial,...)`

Comment: I think he want to update structure from an existing table.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, can you try this?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq;
ALTER TABLE user_event_logs ALTER COLUMN id TYPE BIGINT;
ALTER TABLE user_event_logs ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE user_event_logs ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER SEQUENCE id_seq OWNED BY user_event_logs.id;
```

Comment: For existing rows, don't forget to reset the serial to the current max value of the bigint field.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Well, the difference of `bigserial` and `serial` is 1 is bigint and the other is just int. I've update my answer for matching requirement.